# how to use $match in $cond else section in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to use `$match` in `$cond` in Mongo query and my first try is :

[Query in MongodbPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/diDkganJXfS)

but this error accrued:

> query failed: (InvalidPipelineOperator) Unrecognized expression '$match'

Do you have any idea of using `$match` in `$cond`?

my expected result is :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "b4",
    "coll_C": "c2",        // the nearest date to "2020-08-01" that has coll_C value is: "2020-07-01" so added the "coll_C:"c2"
    "coll_D": "d1",
    "coll_E": "e2",
    "date": "2020-08-01"
  },
  {
    "_id": "b2",
    "coll_C": "c2",
    "coll_D": "d2",        // the nearest date to "2020-07-01" that has coll_D value is: "2020-06-01" so added the "coll_D:"d2"
    "coll_E": "e1",        // the nearest date to "2020-07-01" that has coll_E value is: "2020-05-01" so added the "coll_E:"e1"
    "date": "2020-07-01"
  },
  {
    "_id": "b1",
    "coll_C": "c1",
    "coll_D": "d2",
    "coll_E": "e1",        // the nearest date to "2020-06-01" that has coll_E value is: "2020-05-01" so added the "coll_E:"e1"
    "date": "2020-06-01"
  },
  {
    "_id": "b3",
    "coll_C": "c3",
    "coll_D": "d3",
    "coll_E": "e1",
    "date": "2020-05-01"
  }
]
```

- if it has each of the `coll_C` or `coll_D` or `coll_E`, show that.
- if it has not each of the `coll_C` or `coll_D` or `coll_E`, get the nearest `coll_C` or `coll_D` or `coll_E` base on `date` field from other documents.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: `$match` is a [pipeline stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/index.html#stages). You cannot use a stage within another stage like `$project`. You can use [aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) within a stage.